# Knuth's multiplication hash function via bit shifting

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I tried to implement Knuth's multiplication algorithm via bit shifting with A = 2654435769
and hash size of 2^p elements
But the non-shifting and shifting algorithms give different result

There is how I tried to implement this two alg:

```
    template
    int mult_hash_simple(int key)
    {
        double A = 0.61803398863412439823150634765625;
        double exp = A*key;
        return max_key*(exp - (int) exp);
    }

    template
    int mult_hash_advanced(int key)
    {
    //  const int w = 32;
        const unsigned long long A = 2654435769;
        unsigned long long r0 = key*A;

        return r0 & (  (1
```

UPD: updated some var types. The problem still exist

Comment: Try it with `long long` for `A` as well.

Comment: Example calls with output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below function has the advanced hash logic that is equal to mult_hash_simple function.

```
template<int max_key_power, int p>
int mult_hash_advanced(int key)
{
//  const int w = 32;
    const long long w_bit = 4294967295; // Integer representation of binary value that has last 32 ( which is w value )  bits as 1
    const int A = 2654435769; 
    long long r0 = key*A;


    return (( r0 & w_bit ) >> ( 32 - p ) ) ;
}
```